Let `rr` ignore some child processes
I'm trying to set up rr as a production debugger, recording debug information, but not interrupting the process to be debugged.
The main process (the one that I indent to refix with rr record) spawns a rather large number of subprocesses, since it needs to interact with the OS, so there are many children that I'm not interested in.
Since we want to use this as a lightweight recording debugger, the overhead of instrumenting all children is rather bad, as it bloats the debug traces, and slows down those child processes too.
valgrind has an option to opt out of tracing and analyzing based on a regex matching the process binary file, with the --trace-children-skip option. Now we're wondering if something like this exists for rr too, or if a combination of gdbserver and some other tools could achieve what we want here (postmortem debugging).
